# How can I get more than 20 status's from the LinqToTwitter status?

Tags: tweets, linq-to-twitter

I'm using this code to read `status` items from `Twitter` via `LinqToTwitter`.

```
IQueryable<Status> tweets = 
    twitterCtx.Status.Where(z => z.ScreenName == "HTM_Reisinfo" && z.Type == StatusType.User).Take(100);
```

But whatever number I pass to `Take()`, I only get 20.

Can I get more than 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API does status paging through cursors, which LINQ to Twitter does support. Here's a related post with more explanation:

[Return all tweets from my timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639108/return-all-tweets-from-my-timeline)

Comment: huh? that's a weird notation,` tweet.Count == 200`, this way it looks like every tweet has a count property... I'll give it a try